# System.import is deprecated in webpack2 in favor of import. But, import raises error

Tags: angular, webpack-2

I am working on a project in Angular 4 with Webpack 2.

According to this: https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting-async/#system-import-is-deprecated  `System.import` is deprecated in webpack2 and will be removed in a future version.

But, in the following code:

```
if (filteredItems[0].jQuery == true)
{
    // Load jQuery and jQuery.Validate
    System.import(/* webpackChunkName: "jquery" */ '../../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js');
    System.import(/* webpackChunkName: "jquery.validate" */ '../../node_modules/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js');
    System.import(/* webpackChunkName: "additional-methods" */ '../../node_modules/jquery-validation/dist/additional-methods.js');
 }
```

If I try to change `System.import` to `import`, the following error is raised in VS Code and at build time.

> Declaration or statement expected.

From my package.json I see I am running the most current version:  `"webpack": "^2.4.1",`

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import()` is not yet implemented in TypeScript.

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12364

TypeScript does not ignore it but transpile it to something else which breaks the code. So to use the `import()` you can use loader that will be executed AFTER the typescript transpilation process.

Comment: Wow, that github issue went on and on.   So, are we saying webpack2 is getting ahead of themselves by saying System.import will be deprecated -- since TypeScript hasn't made the change yet?

Comment: I do not follow what they are going to do :)